# HiveContext not keeping SparkContext conf

Tags: python, hive, pyspark

I am unable to adjust the executor and driver memories.

```
 from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
 from pyspark.sql import HiveContext  

 conf = pyspark.SparkConf().setAll([('spark.executor.memory', '2g'),('spark.driver.memory','2g')])
 sc.stop() 

 sc = pyspark.SparkContext(conf=conf)
 sc._conf.getAll()
 hc = HiveContext(sc)
 sc._conf.getAll()
```

When `sc._conf.getAll()` is ran prior to `hc = HiveContext(sc)`, I can see that my memories have been adjusted as needed. However when `sc._conf.getAll()` is run after `hc = HiveContext(sc)` the memories revert to the default.

Answer (score 0):

If is possible use `SparkSession` (available since Spark 2.0) instead of `SparkContext`, so you may add configurations within .conf

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
warehouseLocation = "/hive/user/location"
spark2 = SparkSession\
.builder.appName("SparkAppName")\
.config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", warehouseLocation)\
.config("spark.executor.memory", "2g")\
.config("spark.executor.executor", "3g")\
.enableHiveSupport()\
.getOrCreate()
```